# How to use POST on Buttons href -option

Tags: php, html, css

Could someone please tell me how to use POST with buttons href = ""  option. Do i need javascript or how can I do it?

I need to use POST on my form to transmit the user inputs to PHP script and I was wondering can you do it with href and how? (form action is not an option) If someone would be so kind as to show an example or give a link how to do it.

**I used this for the form:

```
<form name="assetform" action="formaction.php"  method="post">
```

and this for the button:

```
<a class="button" input type="submit" name="deluser" href= "javascript:document.assetform.submit()">
```

But it does not seem to carry the information over to formaction.php . So could you tell me what I am doing wrong with this way?**

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Javascript, to POST data to a script without the use of a form.

jQuery post with JSON response:

```
$.post("your_receiving_script.php", {
    postData: "something something something"
}, function(response) {
    // Do something with response.
    alert(response);
}, 'json');
```

This could be in a function or called with a 'click' event.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Answer to your EDIT

To post through a form you need the `<input>` tags:

```
<form action="processing_script.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="" name="theinput" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post, Save, Whatever" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two common ways:

1. Have ordinary form with POST method and have JavaScript code to submit the form upon clicking the link.
2. Use AJAX, for example jQuery let you Post anything you like with one line of code without having any HTML form.

By the way, button has no `href` attribute - only HTML anchors have this.

Comment: Or just use submit button and style it to look like a HTML anchor.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `method="post"` for  parent of button, in this way you have to put target URL in the

Answer (score 0):

If you mean somehow appending data onto the end of the `href` address, that can't be done.  Only works as `get`.

Otherwise, @Shadow Wizard's answers work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that Henkka. Href just tells browser to request another page. That request can have get parameters along with url. POST contents are passed along with the content and href is not designed to do that. For that we need to use AJAX. [jQuery provides and easy method to perform POST](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). If it is an application for large amount of users, go for normal submit button. jQuery works only if javascript is enabled in the users browser.